# Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val' Line:14

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

I am trying to traverse a tree but getting above error. Please help me out. I am trying to call a definition of same class and as parameter sending a class object. But calling definition not able to identify type of parameters.

```
Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode(object):
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.left = None
         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
     def same(self, s, t):
        if(s is None and t is None):
            return True
        if(s is None or t is None):
            return False
        return s.val==t.val and self.same(s.left,t.left) and self.same(s.right,t.right)

     def traverse(self, s,  t):
        return (s!="" and (self.same(s,t) or self.traverse(s.left,t) or self.traverse(s.right,t)))

     def isSubtree(self, s, t):
        # print s.val
        return self.traverse(s,t)
```

Comment: You are testing for `""` but not for `None`.

Comment: `if(s=="" or t==""):` can be more `Pythonic` like `if s or t:`  other else ~~

Comment: yeah..I know that. but that's not my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like it is the `''` check as opposed to a `None` check in traverse. It will pass `None` values to same because of this.

Comment: How but? I am still confused, bro.The Problem is solved. I just want to know how None makes a difference

Comment: Just use `s is not None`, instead of `s!=''`. Those mean different things.

Comment: So when I write **s!=''"** will it cast **s** automatically?

Comment: There is no automatic casting in Python. When you do `s!=''`, it just checks   if the value of `s` is `''`, which it won't ever be (always a `TreeNode` or `None`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that t and s are TreeNode objects, where do you declare them? Is it possible that you're passing undeclared variables to Solution?

Comment: yes. I am calling **isSubtree** of Solution. I am able to print s.val in **isSubtree** but not in Other definitions